# MySQL JOIN when one table's rows must be appended to columns in result

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of this form, which captures registrations to events:

```
id|name|email|eventid
```

Call it t1

There is also a table of custom fields used to add additional info for a registration. The custom field table is

```
id|customfield_name|customfield_value|parentid
```

Call it t2

So if I have 5 additional custom fields for the event registration, for a single registration in t1, there would be 5 separate rows in t2.

parentid refers to id in first table.

If I do an inner join, something like this,

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.customfield_value
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.parentid = t1.id
WHERE t1.eventid = 2 AND t2.customfield_name='some custom field'
```

then the result is ok. I see name from t1 and one custom field from t2 side by side. But I want to be able to display more than one data_name as a col. So that the result would be something like

```
name|custom field 1|custom field 2|etc
```

I can not figure out how to use JOIN syntax to accomplish this. I am not well versed in MySQL and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Edit:

Ok Strawberry, here is the sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37172/1

If joining with one customfield, the result is almost what I am looking for, except I would want the column label to be the name of the customfield, and not 'value'. I am trying to figure out how to produce this result, which corresponds to a joining of the registrations table where eventid=2, and the customfields that correspond to the registrations for that eventid. So the desired result is

```
name  | workphone | mobile | nationality
Name1   112233      223344   US
Name2   334455      445566   DE
```

Thanks!

Comment: A question: all the custom fields are on the same table?

Comment: Can you edit this with some sample data and expected results?

Comment: `id` has no real purpose here does it - because (`parent_id`,`customfield_name`) is always UNIQUE? Beyond that, I suggest you consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi  Galma88, yes, custom fields are all in one table.

Comment: Ok, edited my question and added the sqlfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianHuether thanks for editing your question. I have changed my answer now that I understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

McAdam331's solution is faster, but the following is a little cleaner on the page:

```
SELECT r.name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c.customfield = 'workphone' THEN c.value END) workphone
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c.customfield = 'mobile' THEN c.value END) mobile
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c.customfield = 'nationality' THEN c.value END) nationality
  FROM registrations r
  JOIN customfields c
    ON c.parentid = r.id
 WHERE r.eventid = 2
 GROUP
    BY r.name;
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. I can see how to get McAdam331's approach to work, but above works and labels the columns. I am never amazed by how much one learns on this site! The site does not let me up-vote, but this answer has my vote.

Comment: @BrianHuether if this is the answer you choose to solve your problem, you can let other readers know by accepting it and clicking the checkmark next to the answer. It's just as, if not more important, than an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to write subqueries to get the work phone, and mobile phone for each person by using a join like this:

```
SELECT r.name, c.value AS workPhone
FROM registrations r
LEFT JOIN customFields c ON c.parentId = r.id AND c.customField = 'workphone';
```

By using a left join this will just return null if a person doesn't have a work phone. Note that this will not work well if the user has multiple workphones, but I'm assuming for this answer's purpose that won't happen.

You can write a similar query to get mobile phone and nationality, and once you have those you can join the queries together to get the values. Try this:

```
SELECT r.name, w.value AS workPhone, m.value AS mobile, n.value AS nationality
FROM registrations r
LEFT JOIN customFields w ON w.parentID = r.id AND w.customField = 'workphone'
LEFT JOIN customFields m ON m.parentID = r.id AND m.customField = 'mobile'
LEFT JOIN customFields n ON n.parentID = r.id AND n.customField = 'nationality';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37172/3) example.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be straightforward to edit your query to add column labels, as opposed to the custom fields being labeled 'value'? I thought that the query as is would do that with the AS statements, but the result in the SQL Fiddle is not so. Regards

Comment: That must be some peculiarity of SQLfiddle. It will work as you expect in your production environment.

Comment: @BrianHuether very strange, this usually works in SQL Fiddle but I get the same thing as you. As Strawberry said, it should work fine in whatever environment you run this in.

Comment: Yes, worked fine in actual environment. I really think both answers are equally good, and really interesting to learn the two equivalent approaches. I think this site should allow one to check off more than one accepted answer. Thanks to both you and Strawberry!

Answer (score -1):

I understand better the problem. Indeed, as @McAdam331 answered, one solution would consist in setting 3 left join (one for each custom field you have)